# StatefulWidget: Which import and does it matter?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I create a new `SatefulWidget` I can import 3 different files:

[image]

Does it matter which import I use? Or is it a problem if I switch between widgets in my app and each widget uses different import?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of them, in both files it points to the same abstract [class](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2ad5376a06ee138e63266bd55dc3d33fc7b1c3eb/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L794).

However, for the seek of readability, you should use one which you already have imported in your file.

Answer (score 1):

O can choose,

If u want to build a app based on Material UI (GOOGLE ANDROID) layout:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material

If u want to build a app based on Cupertino UI (IOS) layout,

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino

**EDIT1:**

We can see the automatic change of visual design for and ios in this post:
[Does Flutter automatically display Cupertino UI in iOS and Material in Android with a single codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184105/does-flutter-automatically-display-cupertino-ui-in-ios-and-material-in-android-w)

Comment: Can I also mix those two across my app?

Comment: Yes, u can, but it gonna to be strange u are using an interface of google material and in the next screen the IOS ui. U can see this post to display the ui in especific versions of phones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184105/does-flutter-automatically-display-cupertino-ui-in-ios-and-material-in-android-w

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797821/what-is-the-difference-between-flutter-packages-widgets-dart-material-dart-and